# Override functions not working after theme installation in prestashop

Tags: module, themes, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I developed a module to override class and controller files. In controller, I tried to override the `ordercontroller.php` file and everything works fine in prestashop default theme. But once I changed the theme that override functions is not working.

I have uninstalled the module after theme installation and again installed and deleted the `cache_index.php` file before module install.. but still override is not working. Can anyone help me, I don't know where am making mistake.I am using PS version 1.5.6.0

Answer (score 1):

you should delete the class_index.php. you can find it inside the cache folder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: the class_index.php will have all function locations so if you delete this after you add the override function it will be change.

Answer (score 0):

**For the problem of not showing functionality of overrode modules**

On Prestashop 1.6 go to your back office and go to `module and services > module and services` search for the module and reset it.